# preg_replace is leaving two white spaces

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using a preg_replace to remove unwanted content from a string, it is working but it is leaving 2 spaces, so...

```
 $content = '[content I want deleted including square brackets] this would be content that I want left!';

 $result = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]\`','',$content);

  echo $result;
```

this above produces the following ("__"represents two spaces)

__this would be content that I want left!

the result should be...

this would be content that I want left!

without the preceding two spaces, can someone tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Your regex doesn't look for `\s` spaces. Could also just use `trim()`. And why is the last backtick escaped?

Comment: [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) and done. Don't be afraid to use more than one function to complete a task

Comment: I am a little bit new to php and although most of the time I can read the code and understand it now this is escaping me still. It reminds me of htaccess. Thank you so much for the help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about your code but i tested this and work well

```
$content = '[content __I want deleted including square brackets] this would be content that I want left!';

 $result = preg_replace('#\[([^\]]*)\]#is','',$content);

  echo $result;
```

(I use "is" cause I always forget the meaning of pattern modifiers and they always works well, if you dont know check http://php-regex.blogspot.it/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add optional spaces at the end of the regex:

```
$content = '[content I want deleted including square brackets] this would be content that I want left!';
$result = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]\s*`', '', $content);
echo $result;
```

This gives:

```
this would be content that I want left!
```

without spaces at the begining.